# Where should I save my automation test screenshots in Unreal Engine for AWS Device Farm?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, unreal-engine5, aws-device-farm

I develop a game with Unreal Engine and covering it with the automation tests. During the tests I take screenshots. Now I decided to run my tests with AWS Device Farm and I can not figure out where to save my screenshots to pull them out with. How do I get the absolute path to "application sandbox"/(Documents/Library/Media) with Unreal Engine C++ code. [AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bXQH.png)

The path to the Documents folder (according to the log file) was : /tmp/scratchA5jsh1.scratch/app-sandbox-mount-tXrZsG/Documents/

I tried to find all the paths that match this pattern using the iOS device's environmental variables and UE FPaths. I have not found anything even remotely similar..